# How can I change dictionary value by press a key?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, keyboard

```
import tkinter as tki
from deneme import Komutlar

obj=Komutlar()

panel.bind("w",obj.forward)

if obj.komutlar["w"] == "True":
    print("w")

panel.mainloop()
```

I made some changes to the code. I create an "Komutlar" object. When I press "w" printing "True". Here the Komutlar py:

```
class Komutlar():

    def __init__(self):
        self.komutlar={"w":"False","s":"False","a":"False","d":"False"}

def forward(self,event):

    self.komutlar["w"] = "True"
    print(self.komutlar["w"])
```

İt is working. But I want to make a action with if statement. İf statment still not working. İs it about mainloop again?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  You're not displaying it after the key press.

Comment: Also, you should use actual `bool` values (`True` and `False`) rather than strings.

Comment: Tkinter panel is opening. I am pressing "w". I need to show w on the command panel because I print it. But printing nothing.

Comment: I tried the code and it works, try to add `print(komutlar["w"])` to `forward` function and it should work.

Comment: You may want to see [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/12139738).

Comment: @DYD Hmm yes you are right. But why if statement is not working?

Comment: @DYD I will check it. Thank you.